# PyCharm DB Navigator: how to fix "No such file or directory"

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, psql, intellij-plugin

I'm running PyCharm Community 2018.3 with the DB Navigator plugin. I've set up a connection and tested it.  When I execute the SQL script

```
SELECT *
FROM table;
```

The DB execution console replies:

```
Creating temporary script file /tmp/DBN-4213556526222248783.sql
Executing command: /usr/bin/psql --echo-all --host=hostname.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --dbname=foo --username=bar -f "/tmp/DBN-4213556526222248783.sql"
Mar 9, 2019 11:24:44 AM: CIQ / CIQ - Script execution started
"/tmp/DBN-4213556526222248783.sql": No such file or directory
```

The /tmp/DBN- file exists and is world readable. /usr/bin/psql exists. I can cut and paste the same 'Executing Command' line into a shell and get a response from the database using it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is tracked under ticket https://database-navigator.atlassian.net/browse/DBN-298

Comment: FWIW, the ticket is still open and the problem still persists as of 2021-01-19 (can confirm based on personal bitter experience :-) ). MacOS 10.14, latest DB plugin within PyCharm CE.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that I run into this problem today on Intellij IDEA Community Edition 2021.1.3. `Build #IC-211.7678.21`